# Can I have a copy of the Stack Overflow CAPTCHA?

Tags: support, captcha

I want to use the captcha system that is used by Stack Overflow. Where can I get the script for this?

Answer (score 9):

Stackoverflow uses [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). In fact, there is a help button you can click which brings up this page: http://recaptcha.net/popuphelp/

> A CAPTCHA is a program that can tell whether its user is a human or a computer. You've probably seen them — colorful images with distorted text at the bottom of Web registration forms. CAPTCHAs are used by many websites to prevent abuse from "bots," or automated programs usually written to generate spam. No computer program can read distorted text as well as humans can, so bots cannot navigate sites protected by CAPTCHAs.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Edit: As Jonah Bron suggested, meta.stackoverflow.com might be more appropriate for this question. You can see other captcha-related questions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha